# Dynamically Generating Web Page with new URL

Tags: php, ajax

Is there any way to generate webpages dynamically.for example I have a website called abc.com in which I have included a form with many fields.

When a user submit this form,I want a new webpage abc.com/xyz to be created.Wondering if this is possible.

Comment: Yes that possible. But you only need to write the logic for all those things.

Comment: I think you are new to PHP. That's what PHP is made for. Regarding the format of the URL, you will need to learn about URL rewriting. You can always bing that. By the way, I wonder why some people downvote new users to SO (and PHP?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Anything is possible in programming/development.
See the following PHP manual for a good tutorial: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in variety of ways.

You can pass GET variables in URL `(example.com/page?var1=1&var2=2)` and use this variables to generate unique page by predefined template.

If you don't want to use variables in URL, you can POST them to page via form request or ajax call.

Alternatively you can use .htaccess configuration files to rewrite your URL and use url segments as variables `(example.com/var1/var2)`, this is common approach in MVC systems, where first/second variables are class/method names.

So here's an example:

1. You have a page.php where form resides.
2. User fills a form and submits it.
3. Form goes trough AJAX call, submitting it to request.php page
4. request.php parses it and stores it in DB, generating unique id
5. AJAX event recieves from request.php a unique id and redirects user to review.php
   with url `(example.com/review/uniqueID)` or `(example.com/review.php?uniqueID)`
6. review.php recieves uniqueId, get's info from DB by it and displays requested info

Comment: This is something I dont want to do rather I want to generate new web page each time with different url.say if user submits a form with a field called name=xyz in abc.com then I want abc.com/xyz to be generated.similarly if user submits with name=pqr then I want abc.com/pqr to be generated.

Comment: This is something you SHOULD do if you want to code. There is no easy way to "generate magic".